# Does anyone know why this error occurs?

Tags: ibm-mq

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ2007: Failed to send a message to destination 'Queue Name'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQPUT or MQPUT1; however WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:498)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:216)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1086)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1044)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.access$800(WMQMessageProducer.java:71)
```

Comment: you should provide more information, don't just submit a stacktrace. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question so we can help you

Comment: Check the Websphere MQ message/error logs for details , as the error is originating in MQ.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please add more details.  The linked exception referenced will tell you the reason the PUT failed and is key to knowing why beyond a guess of multiple possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

Is 'Queue Name' queue that you are trying to put message? That queue does not exist on the queue manager your application is connected to. A queue must exist before you can put a message. Create a (or using existing) queue in your queue manager and try again.